# htaccess make folder inaccessible but files accessible to server?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the folder 'videos' and inside numerous mp4 files.  I've added this htaccess file to the folder.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Now when i try to access the directory via browser it is inaccessible but when i play a video from the file i can't play?

If i remove the .htaccess, i can play the files again.  I put the `allow from` server ip address, so the files should still be able to be accessed by the server?

How do i solve?

Comment: how are you trying to play the video? you probably dont need the allow at all

Comment: i'm using fv flowplayer and i pass the video url to the shortcode parameter via php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent the index of a directory in your .htaccess

```
//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: You are welcome! please accept the answer if it's solved.

Comment: this would still make the files directly accessible.

Comment: Great answer, needed the exact thing, tried it .. works like a charm!